# How do I programmatically render a component in VueJS 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dependency-injection, modal-dialog, vuejs3

I'm using VueJS 3. I'm trying to create a dialog service that can be injected into various components throughout the application and then used to open a dialog. For example:

Ideal State using composition API:

**random_component.js**

```js
<template>
    <div class="header-controls-layout">
        <div class="left">
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Media Library
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <button @click="openUploadModal()">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import UploadMediaModal from '@/Components/UploadMediaModal.vue'

const dialogService = inject('dialog');// Inject dialog service

function updateTileSize(size){
    this.tileSize = size;
}

function openUploadModal(){
   //Open a dialog and pass a component to render with optional settings
   dialogService.open(UploadMediaModal, {data: {}, width: '800px', height: '80vh'});
}

</script>
```

As you'll notice, I'm injecting the key 'dialog'. I'm registering this in app.js just before mount the application.

**app.js**

```js
const vueapp = createApp();
        
VueSingleton.prototype.$vue = vueapp;
const instance = new DialogService("dialog-container");
vueapp.provide('dialog', instance);

vueapp.use(plugin);
vueapp.mixin({ methods: { route } });
vueapp.component('Dialog', Dialog);
vueapp.mount('#app');
```

**dialog.service.js**

```js
import { VueSingleton } from "./singleton.vue";
import { ref, onUnmounted, createVNode, render } from 'vue';

export class DialogService extends VueSingleton {
    _container = null;
    _container_selector = '';
    _modals = [];
    

    constructor(selector){
        super();
        this._container_selector = selector;
    }

    open(component, {data, width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight}){

        this._container = window.document.getElementById(this._container_selector);

        let appContext = this.$vue._context.app._instance.appContext; // Seems wrong to me
        let vnode = createVNode('Dialog', {component, data, width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight});

        vnode.appContext = {...appContext };
        render(vnode, this._container);    
    }
}
```

**singleton.vue.js**

```js
export class VueSingleton{}
```

**Up until this point, everything works as expected more or less.**

Firing the `openUploadModal` method in method in the `random_component.js` up above, injects the dialog component into the DOM. I can see the dialog component in the document tree inspector.

However this is where the problem begins. As you can see, in the `random_component.js` above I'm passing a component(`UploadMediaModal`) to the open method.

**The goal here is that I would like to render this component(`UploadMediaModal`) in the dialog component.** But the Dialog component isn't rendering it's template or even firing it's lifecycle hooks.

***Why isn't the dialog component rendering? Additionally, how do I programmatically render another component inside the dialog component?***

Here is the dialog component:
Dialog.vue

```js
<script setup>
    import { ref, onUnmounted, getCurrentInstance,h, createVNode, render, onMounted } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps(["component", "data", "width", "max-width", "height", "max-height"]);
    const container = ref();
    const { appContext } = getCurrentInstance();
    
    onMounted(() => {
        // Not Firing
        renderDialog();
    })

    // Destory Comp on unmount
    onUnmounted(() => {
        render(null, container);
    });

    function renderDialog(){
        
        let vnode = createVNode(props.component, props.data || {});
        vnode.appContext = {...appContext };
        render(vnode, container);
    }
</script>

<template>
  <transition name="modal-fade">
    <div class="modal-backdrop">
      <div class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-describedby="modalContent" :style="{'width': props.width || '600px', 'max-width': props.maxWidth || '100%', 'height': props.height || '400px', 'max-height': props.maxHeight || '80vh'}">
        <!-- Modal Injecttion Container -->
        <div ref="container" class="modal-body" id="modalContent"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<style>
  .modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .modal {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }


  .modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }

  .btn-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #4AAE9B;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .btn-green {
    color: white;
    background: #4AAE9B;
    border: 1px solid #4AAE9B;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }

  .modal-fade-enter,
  .modal-fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .modal-fade-enter-active,
  .modal-fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
  }
</style>
```

UploadMediaModal.vue

```js
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
    <p>Upload Media Modal component working!</p>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Can't say why it doesn't work. But the approach is unnecessarily complicated. It's <component> to render inside current component (to render a specific modal), and <teleport> to render outside (something you may often want for modal container). You may need both. provide/inject is unnecessary, since service import is global, you can just import it. VueSingleton class is unnecessary, if you need to access app instance, you could just import it in a module. render(null, container) - this doesn't destroy an instance but creates memory leak, something to be aware when using DOM directly.